# Why is strtok() splitting words and limiting words to 7 characters in C?

Tags: c

I have been searching everywhere for the past two days and cannot figure this out. Here is a small sample of the output:

It should read "and find a pleasure":

and

f

ind

a

p

leasure

================

length   count

================

1   9054

2   10102

3   9336

4   5944

5   3311

6   1656

7   1292

================

average 2.86

================

Below is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#define DELIM " ,.;:'\"&!? -_\n\t\0"

int process(int *count, char *buffer);
int printOut(int *count);

int main() {
    char *buffer = (char *) calloc(1, 50*sizeof(char*));
    int *count =(int*) calloc(50, 50*sizeof(long));

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin)) {
        process(count, buffer);
    }

    printOut(count);
    free(count);
    return 0;
}

int process(int *count, char *buffer) {
    int word_len=0, i;
    char *pch;
    pch = strtok(buffer, DELIM);
    while (pch != NULL) {
        for(i=0; pch[i] != '\0'; i++) {
                word_len++;
        }
        count[word_len]++;
        word_len=0;
        printf("%s\n", pch);
        pch = strtok(NULL, DELIM);
    }
    return 0;
}

int printOut(int *count) {
    int i;
    double num=0;
    double total=0;
    double average=0;
    printf("================\n");
    printf("len  count\n");
    printf("================\n");
    for(i=0;i<50;i++){
        if(count[i]!=0){
            num=count[i]+num;
            total=total+(count[i]*i);
            printf("%d   %d\n",i,count[i]);
        }
    }
    average = total/num;
    printf("================\n");
    printf("average %.2f\n", average);
    printf("================\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried printing out what is pointed to by `pch` before you do the strtok?

Comment: **sizeof(char*)** are you sure that is char* inside the size of operator ?

Comment: `sizeof(buffer)` is the size of a pointer. Declare buffer as `char buffer[50]` if you want to use sizeof.

Comment: You don't need to cast the return value of `malloc` in a C program.

Comment: okay so I allocated memory for `pch` like this `char *pch = calloc(1, 50*sizeof(char*));` then printed and I go 50 zeros like I expected, but now the output looks like this:0simple
0joys
0remembe
0ring
he
0r
own
c
0hild
li

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to note that the assignment requires me to use either `malloc` or `calloc`

Comment: The problem isn't malloc() or calloc().  For example, `char buffer[BUF_LEN];` is absolutely equivalent (in this context) to `char *buffer = malloc (BUF_LEN);`.

Comment: `sizeof` only works on arrays, not pointers (unless you do want the actual size of a pointer). A char is always one byte, so you can just do `char *buffer = malloc(50);` and then use 50 rather than `sizeof buffer`.

Comment: @paulsm4, those are defintiely not equivalent.  The former is an automatic variable and will be deallocated when it goes out of scope.  The latter requires an explicit `free()`.  Also, your first example makes an array and the second example a pointer, though for the use case here, that really doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @Carl Norum - they *are* equivalent in this case.  The *only* difference is "stack allocation" vs. "heap allocation" - and that's IRRELEVANT in this particular example (where the allocation occurs in "main()").

Comment: @paulsm4, for the use of the variable, yes.  You still need a `free()` at the end, though.  Your operating system might let you get away with playing fast & loose, but that's not really a good habit to get into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
 char *buffer = (char *) calloc(1, 50*sizeof(char*));
```

It should be:

```
 sizeof(char) // or since this is always 1: 'calloc(1, 50)'
```

But the real problem is here:

```
fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
```

Sizeof buffer is 4 (or whatever the sizeof pointer is) because it is a pointer, you need to do this:

```
fgets(buffer, 50, stdin);
```

Also the `sizeof(long)` in the calloc call for `count` is not to the point, there you need `sizeof(int)` otherwise you may be allocating more bytes then you are intending to (depending on the architecture). So this can be:

```
int *count =(int*) calloc(50, sizeof(int));
```

Comment: Why not just delete the `sizeof(char)` part entirely?

Comment: In deed, there's no reason why not, sizeof char is 1

Comment: Carl is right. `sizeof(char) == 1` by definition. http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/sizeof-char.html

Comment: Amazing, thank you. Spend so much time reading and trying to figure something out and its that easy. Should have came here first. Thank you

Comment: The `calloc` call isn't actually incorrect, except that it likely allocates 4 or 8 times too much memory. But `char *buffer = malloc(50);` would probabl do as well, as long as you don't read bytes that you haven't explicitly written.

Comment: also, the `sizeof(char*)` was me trying to figure out what was going wrong. Forgot to change it back, thank you

Comment: @Keith Thompson. I'm not sure, but is not calloc (50,50*sizeof long) the cause of garbage values in int*count ??

Comment: @qPCR4vir: that would allocate and clear space for 50 longs, it wouldn't affect any other variables as an int can't be longer than a long.

Comment: (Actually, no, that would allocate space for 2,500 longs!)

Answer (score 0):

```
int main() {
    char *buffer =  calloc(50, 1);
    int  *count  =  calloc(50, sizeof(int));

    while (fgets(buffer, 50, stdin)) {
        process(count, buffer);
    }
```

Your original fgets only "read" sizeof pointer: 4 or 8 byte, and not the entery buffer, or 50 char , with is what you want.

Comment: Thank you, such an easy fix.

Answer (score 0):

This counter-example might help:

```
/*
 * Sample output:
 *   word= and, length(word)= 3
 *   word= find, length(word)= 4
 *   word= a, length(word)= 1
 *   word= pleasure, length(word)= 8
 *   Done.
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUF_LEN 50
#define DELIM " ,.;:'\"&!? -_\n\t\0"

void process(int *count, char *buffer);

int main() {
  char buffer[BUF_LEN];
  int count[BUF_LEN];

  strcpy (buffer, "and find a pleasure");
  process(count, buffer);

  printf ("Done.\n");
  return 0;
}

void process(int *count, char *buffer) {
  char *pch = strtok(buffer, DELIM);
  while (pch) {
    printf ("word= %s, length(word)= %d\n",
      pch, strlen(pch));
    pch = strtok (NULL, DELIM);
  }
}
```